# Is Nietzsche's goal -- for the "overman" and "higher type" -- just 'forgetfulness'?

Tags: nietzsche, nihilism, buddhism, art, modernism

Is Nietzsche's goal -- for the overman and higher type of human being -- **just** the Buddhist concept of "forgetfulness" or dukkha?

I am asking because it makes sense in my -- somewhat -- Buddhist world view, and the value I place on modernism's revolutionary characteristic.

Comment: Do you mean forgetfulness in the specifically Buddhist sense of [Muṣitasmṛtitā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muṣitasmṛtitā)? And I don't really see a connection to Nietzsche's overman, can you elaborate on why you think this idea might be related to forgetfulness?

Comment: no not at all, i mean in relation 'dukkha' that's all.

Comment: It would be nice if you could link a passage from Nietzsche that makes you think this, because I'm having a hard time fitting any notion of 'forgetfulness' in with Nietzsche's thought.

Comment: Dukka is usually translated as suffering, or anguish. How can you relate that to forgetfulness? Self-forgetting..? Nietzsche is seriously un-Buddhist, though I feel there is a meaningful resonance between eternal recurrance, and rebirth approached as a thought-experiment which in a world of anatta I see as the only way to interpret it.

Answer (score 1):

Friedrich Nietzsche was someone who somewhat admired Buddhism and said in his writing: "Buddhism already has - and this distinguishes it profoundly from Christianity - the self-deception of moral concepts behind it - it stands, in my language, Beyond Good and Evil." He saw it as promoting '...nihilistic turning away from life, a longing for nothingness, or for life's 'opposite', for a different sort of 'being' as he describes in in *The Genealogy of Morals*. The concept that caused Nietzche to believe this isn't the Buddhist concept of forgetfulness, but the concept of [Dukkha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du%E1%B8%A5kha) - a concept that roughly translates to "suffering' or "unhappiness". It refers to the [painfulness of the mudane life](https://web.utk.edu/~sophia/readings/moad.html#:~:text=In%20The%20Genealogy%20of%20Morals,an%20effort%2C%20through%20restraint%20from) that can be overcome by following a path of enlightenment similar to Buddha. For this, Nietzsche saw the goal of Nirvana and escaping Dukkha was similar to the concept of the overman - similar to Buddha, achieving Nirvana was be a form of life denying nihilism in a form of inversion. So, to Nietzsche, the goal of the overman was related to Dukkha in that - to Nietzsche - overcoming the pain of the mudane life and transcending it with their own sense of morality to reach a personal form of 'nirvana' (ie. overcoming nihilism) was the main goal of the Ubermensch.

Answer (score 0):

> no happiness, no cheerfulness, no hope, no pride, no present, without
> forgetfulness

I think calling that forgetfulness "suffering" (due to pain, impermanence or conditioned existence) is a strange equation. I suppose we might "suffer" when we forget buddha nature

> remember your Buddha Nature. Remember your innate capacity for
> dignity, understanding and vast compassion. These gifts were born into
> you. Discover how the beautiful qualities of Buddha Nature can become
> alive for you, in your heart and the way you live.

https://www.spiritrock.org/buddha-nature

but what would that really mean to Nietzsche? What does Nietzsche think we should forget, our essence?